# Id do objeto criado parece não ficar disponível no form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, typescript, angular

Estou usando Angular com TypeScript e Asp.Net MVC.

Eu crio um objeto e o MVC controller me retorna o objeto. Estou pegando este objeto no TypeScript e automaticamente o ID do objeto vai para o Form por meio do Bind.

Quando eu chamo o método submit de novo, parece que o Form não recebeu o Id. Este Id será usado para eu saber se devo dar um post ou um put.

Sou novato na tecnologia, alguém pode me ajudar?

OBS.: depois de criar um objeto, eu continuo na tela, caso o usuário queira editá-lo. Esta é a melhor forma de implementar?

Segue o método:

```
submit(form){
    this.professor = form.value.htmlProfessor;

    if (this.professor.Id !=""){
      //aqui vou chamar o put
      console.log(this.professor.Id);
    }else{
      this.service.create(this.professor, 
        (response)=> {
          this.professor = response.json(); 
      });        
    }
  }
```

Comment: Sua pergunta não está clara e só este pedaço de código não ajuda no entendimento do problema. Tem como ser um pouco mais específico?

Comment: Outra coisa: você está usando **AngularJS com TypeScript** ou **Angular 2**?

Comment: Desculpe, vou tentar ser mais claro.
1 - Eu mando criar um professor no banco de dados. Esse professor é criado e o Controller MVC me devolve o response (onde está o objeto criado). Eu pego este objeto, e atribuo a professor (this.professor = response.json()). Na tela, eu coloco o Id do novo professor para ser exibido e ele está sendo exibido em um input (type="text"). Se eu, na tela, clico em salvar, esse método que coloquei acima é executado novamente, porém, o Id que está em tela fica em branco dentro deste método. Quero saber como pegar esse Id nesse caso.
2 - Angular4 com TypeScript.

Comment: "Na tela, eu coloco o Id do novo professor". O Id é retornado pelo servidor. Eu não digito nada.